# How looks the windvelocity field around a flat building?

Tags: aerodynamics

Suppose a storm is blowing towards the front of a high, broad and deep building with a flat roof? How does the field which shows the windvelocity looks like? Is there a stable high air pressure in front of the building, around which the storm blows fairly constant (in velocity and direction), or blows the storm with high velocity over the surfaces of the building, diminishing, the farther from the surface?

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score 1):

This is question best answered by a picture, or two, illustrating the effect

You can see by the colors in the picture that friction with the ground reduces  the windspeed is considerably (blue color).  The green color indicates higher wind speeds,  followed by slight red coloration over the top of the house.

[image]

[image]

Related: [Wikipedia Wind Speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_speed)